# Maximal abelian subgroups of an extraspecial group of order $2^{2m+1}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

I've found a proof of the structure of maximal abelian normal subgroups of an extraspecial group of order $2^{2m+1}$ in the book "Endlichen Gruppen I" by B. Huppert but there is a part of the proof I don't quite understand.

Assume $G=\mathcal{D_{1}}*\cdots*\mathcal{D_{m-1}}*\mathcal{Q}$ (the central product of $m-1$ dihedral groups of order $8$ and quaternion). Then takes $U$ a maximal abelian normal subgroup and decomposes the element $a\in U$ into two a product of two elements, i.e., $a=a_{1}a_{2}$ with $a_{1}\in\mathcal{D_{1}}*\cdots*\mathcal{D_{m-1}}$ and $a_{2}\in\mathcal{Q}.$ These elemets are uniquely determined up two a factor of $Z(G).$ Then the subgroups $U_{i}$ are defined as the "product of all $a_{i}", i=1,2$ respectively, where each of the $a_{i}$ picked in their respective groups, and this is the part I don't catch. Does it mean $U_{i}$ is generated by $a_{i}$? Is $U_{i}$ generated by the product of some $a_{i}^{(1)},a_{i}^{(2)},\ldots,a_{i}^{(r)}$? I don't understand how are defined the groups $U_{i}.$

I would greatly appreciate any help or idea.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: Please do not use pictures of symbols for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched, and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to edit it

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, this is a classical result, You know that for any $a \in U$, $\langle a \rangle \leqslant G$, so by Lagrange, you get $$|\langle a \rangle | = o(a) \mid 2^{2m+1} |G|$$

Hence, $o(a)$ is a power of $2$. Then if $\forall a \in U, a^2 = e$ you have $a = a^{-1}$,thus you get for $a,b \in U, \, aba^{-1}b^{-1}= abab = (ab)^2 = e$, hence $U$ is abelian which is absurd.

You thus have some element $a \in U$ such that $a^2 \neq e$ hence $o(a) >2$, so since $o(a) = 2^k$ for some integer $k$, you have $k > 1$. You then need to consider $b= a^{2^{k-2}}$, for $l \in \mathbb{N}^*$, you have $b^l = a^{2^{k-2}l}$, hence if $l < 4$, $2^{k-2}l < 2^k$ and $b^l \neq e$.
And of course $b^4 = a^{2^k} = e$ so $o(b)=4$ and $b \in U$.

You could try to show this result: if $\forall x \in G, \, x^2 = e$, $G$ can be endowed with a $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector space structure. However you should neither not post too many question at a time, nor put links of articles, write them down.

---

For the conclusion of the last paragraph, $U_1 \times U_2$ is the pushout of the inclusions $Z(G) \to U_i$, this gives you the cardinality result

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.

Comment: Thanks for the first part! And the solution to the second I haven't studied pushout, so I can't use it. I think the problem comes with the definition of the subgroups $U_{i}$ where I don't understand what means the author with "product of $a_{i}$", if I could understand it then the result will be easier to follow.

Comment: @Shaun I suggested improvements and even flagged the question...